# How to make pair of list in Lisp

Tags: lisp

I am trying to make pair function with one argument using recursion.
But I don't know how to solve this problem.
Here is my code:

```
(defun makepair (l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((and (atom (car l)) (atom (cdr l))) (list (car l) (cdr l)))
        (t (makepair (cdr l)))
  )
)
```

I have to make `'(1 d 2 c)` to `((1 d) (1 2) (1 c) (d 2) (d c) (2 c))`

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: `mapcon`: for each list, consider its car and cdr. Map each element of the cdr to a pair with car.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   (defun makepair (l)
      (if (atom l) nil
        (append (loop for i in (rest l)
                   collecting (list (car l) i))
          (makepair (rest l)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive version (as required) would look like this:

```
(defun make-pair (l) 
    (when (and l (cdr l)) 
       (append (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (list  (car l) x)) (cdr l)) 
           (make-pair (cdr l)))))

 (make-pair '(1 d 2 c)) =>  ((1 D) (1 2) (1 C) (D 2) (D C) (2 C))
```